# How to superimpose figures in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, figure

I create several figures in multiple modules, and i would like to superimpose them in my`main.py`.

Can i return a usable figure/plot that could be reused in `main.py` to create a combined figure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to setup a figure/axis in main.py and then pass the axis handle to each module. As a minimal example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#from mod import plotsomefunction
#from diffrentmod import plotsomeotherfunction

def plotsomefunction(ax, x):

    return ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def plotsomeotherfunction(ax, x):

    return ax.plot(x,np.cos(x))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,1000)
l1 = plotsomefunction(ax, x)
l2 = plotsomeotherfunction(ax, x)
plt.show()
```

where the functions represent modules.

Alternatively, you could just create a figure in main and add it to the current axis in each module with `plt.sca`. This seems like a much less robust solution.

Comment: Wonderful! thank you so much!
I'm now struggling with an off topic issue: how can i do the same with `basemap` object. More briefly: i create a `basemap` plot in one module and i would like to plot over using other modules. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, `basemap` is not something I've used. It looks like basemap just does the mapping with `matplotlib` still used for the plots. You should therefore be able to add it to current figure/axis in the same way. According to http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html : "You can also plot on the map directly with the matplotlib pyplot [...] using the Axes instance associated with the Basemap." Maybe `ax = map.get_axis()`?

Comment: thank you! unfortunately `basemap` doesn't have `map.get_axis()`.
It does have `map.ax` that can be referenced to an `ax`. I tried it and got: `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_collection'`. Now i need to understand why and how to solve it.

Comment: Hi @EdSmith. Based on your help here i found a solution also to the `basemap` issue i had. I published an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31172618/1659322