# How to create a reusable basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, matplotlib-basemap

In continuation to my previous question: [How to superimpose figures in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104867/how-to-superimpose-figures-in-matplotlib) i would like to know how can one create a reusable `basemap` object.
My problem is that a `basemap` is not a `pyplot` object, so the solution i received works well on `figures / axes` but not on `basemap` objects.

I tried to look around and find a solution, but couldn't find any, just discussions.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason the approach shown in the question you linked to won't work with basemap axes.

Comment: Thanks @joe, but it doesn't work exactly the same. `basemap` objects are not one-to-one `pyplot` objects.

Comment: No, they're not, but they're still objects. You can pass them into a function that then calls their methods just fine.  They have plotting methods very similar to an `Axes` instance, but they have others as well.  If you need the underlying `Axes` instance you can get it with `map._check_ax()` where `map` is your basemap object. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to create a figures in separate modules:
1. creates base map using `basemap`.
2 + 3. create overlay of imshow(2) and plot(3).
My main module allows different combinations of the figures. That why i don't want to create the base map several times.
Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you can call `map.plot(...)` and `map.imshow(...)` directly (where `map` is your `Basemap` instance).   Again, if you want the underlying axes instance you can get it with `map._check_ax()`.

Comment: @joe, thanks! i'll have to check it later on, but it seems like a good direction!

Comment: Hi @joe - i checked it. It seems like it does work, but i can't see the overlay. Maybe it's a matter of coordination shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JoeKington here and @EdSmith at [How to superimpose figures in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104867/how-to-superimpose-figures-in-matplotlib), i was able to understand how to achieve what i wanted: reuse basemap objects and pass them around.

I made it this way:

1. Created a `base_map.py` that has two functions: `plot()` that create a map object and draw some properties and another one, `set_a_map()` that create an empty map object.
2. In the other modules i added to the plot functions a `map=None` property, and in each function i added a:

   ```
   if not map:  
       map = base_map.set_a_map()
   ```

   So that in case that no map object being passed to the other function, the function will create a new map object.
3. In my plot functions, instead of using `plt.imshow(...)` for example, i'm using `map.imshow(...)`. This way my data will be plot over a map.

Thank you for the patience and the really helpful comments!