# How do I keep previous data sets when plotting in a loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data segments that I am loading in a loop and then plotting on a graph, and I want new data segments to be plotted over the previous segments, so that when I'm finished, all the data will be plotted on one graph. I've included the plotting segment below, and it currently just make 22 different plots for the 22 different segments of data.

```
    fig = pl.figure()
    ax1 = pl.subplot(211)
    ax2 = pl.subplot(212)
    external_temp4 = segment.acs.channels["T_BRO4"]
    external_temp2 = segment.acs.channels["T_BRO2"]
    board_temp = board_ss_dataset.channels["mb_temp2"]
    time = (segment.acs.times-segment.acs.times[0])/3600
    board_time = (board_ss_dataset.times-board_ss_dataset.times[0])/3600

    ax1.plot(time, external_temp2,'.k', label = 'BRC2 external temp')
    if num_board+56>=56 and num_board+56<=61:
        ax1.plot(board_time, board_temp, '.', label = "board {0:d}".format(num_board+56))
    box1 = ax1.get_position()
    ax1.set_position([box1.x0, box1.y0, box1.width*0.8, box1.height])
    ax1.set_ylabel("Temperature $^o$C")
    ax1.legend(prop={'size':7},loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

    ax2.plot(time, external_temp4,'.k', label = 'BRC4 external temp')
    if num_board+56>=70 and num_board+56<=77:
        ax2.plot(board_time, board_temp, 'r.', label = "board {0:d}".format(num_board+56))
    box2 = ax2.get_position()
    ax2.set_position([box2.x0, box2.y0, box2.width*0.8, box2.height])
    ax2.legend(prop={'size':7},loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    ax2.set_xlabel("Time in hours {0:d}".format(num_board+1))
    ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature $^o$C")
    pl.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to superimpose figures in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104867/how-to-superimpose-figures-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I'd check out the link in the potential duplicate I flagged.  Also, unrelated, you can do a check like this:  `61 >= num_board+56 >= 56` in python

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is all inside a single loop, just don't call `fig = pl.figure()` every time. That is the process which is creating a new figure. When you call any plot commands, it will automatically plot to the figure in focus, which is always going to be the most recently created figure. You probably want something like this:

```
fig = pl.figure()
ax1 = pl.subplot(211)
ax2 = pl.subplot(212)
for ...:
    external_temp4 = segment.acs.channels["T_BRO4"]
    external_temp2 = segment.acs.channels["T_BRO2"]
    board_temp = board_ss_dataset.channels["mb_temp2"]
    time = (segment.acs.times-segment.acs.times[0])/3600
    board_time = (board_ss_dataset.times-board_ss_dataset.times[0])/3600

    ax1.plot(time, external_temp2,'.k', label = 'BRC2 external temp')
    if num_board+56>=56 and num_board+56<=61:
        ax1.plot(board_time, board_temp, '.', label = "board {0:d}".format(num_board+56))

    ax2.plot(time, external_temp4,'.k', label = 'BRC4 external temp')
    if num_board+56>=70 and num_board+56<=77:
        ax2.plot(board_time, board_temp, 'r.', label = "board {0:d}".format(num_board+56))

box1 = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box1.x0, box1.y0, box1.width*0.8, box1.height])
ax1.set_ylabel("Temperature $^o$C")
ax1.legend(prop={'size':7},loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

box2 = ax2.get_position()
ax2.set_position([box2.x0, box2.y0, box2.width*0.8, box2.height])
ax2.legend(prop={'size':7},loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
ax2.set_xlabel("Time in hours {0:d}".format(num_board+1))
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature $^o$C")
pl.show()
```