# Draw pandas dataplot and mathlib data plot overlaying with eachother

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
plt.figure()
mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))
plt.show()
movieRates.plot.hist(stacked=True)
```

This is what I am trying out but it does not work it gives me a figure 1 and a figure 2. I tried to find an answer but I could not really get anything out of the other examples since they were different from mine. What I am trying to achieve is to show that the movieRates have a normal distribution. That is why I'd like to join those figures together. But I had no luck untill now.

Comment: You want to **overlay** the plots. There are *many* answers that deal with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104867/how-to-superimpose-figures-in-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to superimpose figures in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104867/how-to-superimpose-figures-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @ShawnMehan yes I have been looking at them but did not know what fig or ax means that is why I did not know how to do that in my case

Comment: @ShawnMehan I also have a pandas plot so idk how to do ax.plot() with pandas

Comment: "read the source". Always, always, always. You will answer your own questions and learn so much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `plt.gca()` and then use the `ax` argument of pandas plot.

```
plt.figure()
mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))
ax = plt.gca()
movieRates.plot.hist(stacked=True,ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D I just did not knew where to put the ax in pandas